# Array flatten with recursion

Tags: php, functional-programming

I'd been using this form for a while now with the functional methods map, filter, reduce:

```
// For example...
$result = array_reduce(array_map(function($value) {
    return explode('-', $value);
}, $input), function($carry, $item) {
    return array_merge($carry, $item);
}, array());
```

The `array_reduce()` part, where I need to collapse depth in the result. So I was thinking about this, and this is what I came up with. It actually works as a callback to `array_reduce()` too:

```
/**
 * Flatten a multi-dimensional array to a single-level array,
 * sorting the entries in order to depth first.
 * 
 * @param array $carry Array to initialize, will be the subject if the only argument passed.
 * @param mixed $subject Optional Array or value that has data in potential multi-dimensions.
 * 
 * @return array
 */
function array_flatten(?array $carry = [], $subject = null): array
{
    return array_reduce((array) ($subject ?? $carry), function(array $carry, $item) {
        return is_array($item)
            ? array_flatten($carry, $item) 
            : array_merge($carry, (array) $item);
    }, $subject !== null ? (array) $carry : []); // Don't merge onto the $subject...
}
```

https://3v4l.org/J1NeJ

Thing is, the way it works, I think it literally goes one level further than there are levels to traverse. The reason I think this is because the `array_merge()` is getting passed a "boxed" element. So the way I'm adding to the array is to box/unbox an array wrapper so it can be merged.

That seems like the most amount of extra effort for one little thing; it happens to every non-array it comes across. Questioning whether I should use it.

It can be called like `array_reduce()`:

```
array_reduce([1,2,[3,[4]],5], 'array_flatten');
```

Or more likely:

```
array_flatten([1,2,[3,[4]],5]);
```

Is this something I should avoid?

Answer (score 3):

PHP already has a native function for this task.

`array_walk_recursive()` traverses your "leaf nodes" for you in one step:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae168fa17b634c128afe98d5adc4de5d47459b24))

```
//$multi=[1,2,[3,[4]],5];
$multi=[array('A', 
        array('B',
            array('CC','CCCC','CCCCCC'), 
            array('DDD','EFG','HIJ','LMNOP')
        )
    ), 
    array('2'), 
    'b',
    array(array(),array(),array())];
array_walk_recursive($multi,function($v)use(&$flat){$flat[]=$v;});
var_export($flat);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => 'B',
  2 => 'CC',
  3 => 'CCCC',
  4 => 'CCCCCC',
  5 => 'DDD',
  6 => 'EFG',
  7 => 'HIJ',
  8 => 'LMNOP',
  9 => '2',
  10 => 'b',
)
```

Comment: Yeah, but passing and using a referenced array in functional programming is entirely beside the point. That's simply a shorthand-ish way of writing a recursive for loop without the `for` syntax.

Comment: Also: http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the benefit of being able to call `array_flatten()` from `array_reduce()`.  If there is an important use, please let me know as I'd like to be educated on this point.  My code to follow cannot be called like this: `array_reduce([1,2,[3,[4]],5], 'array_flatten');` as yours was designed to do.

I have made a few modifications and have a php<7 friendly version to offer... more specifically, I've omitted the type (and nullable) declarations and null coalescing operator so that PHP<7 versions can use the snippet.  I'm not suggesting that your type declarations are a bad idea, I only mean to make the function more usable to a wider audience.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8595a0f62c592bc2421e60fc0f8ec5fa2a71096))

```
$multi=[['A',['B',['CC','CCCC','CCCCCC'],['DDD','EFG','HIJ','LMNOP']]],['2'],'b',[[],[],[]]];

function array_flatten($array,$accumulator=[]){
    return array_reduce($array,function($carry,$item){
        return is_array($item) ? array_flatten($item,$carry) : array_merge($carry,[$item]);
    }, $accumulator);
}
var_export(array_flatten($multi));
```

Comment: There isn't a benefit, it's just that it fits the same signature. That was for the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just working on arrays this might satisfy your functional urge for selecting out of a deep data structure:

```
function recursive_select(
    $data,
    callable $callback,
    $flag = RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    $preserve_keys = FALSE
) {
    return iterator_to_array(new CallbackFilterIterator(
        new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator($data),
            $flag
        ), 
        $callback
    ), $preserve_keys);
}
```

Usage here: https://3v4l.org/TDIvu

```
$multi=[['A',['B',['CC','CCCC','CCCCCC'],['DDD','EFG','HIJ','LMNOP']]],['2'],'b',[[],[],[]]];
$array = array(1,2,[3,4],5,'six',array(array('78',9)),10);


$multi_output = recursive_select($multi, function ($value, $key, $iterator) : bool {
  return is_string($value);
});

$array_output = recursive_select($array, function ($value, $key, $iterator) : bool {
    return is_numeric($value) || is_string($value);
});

var_dump($multi_output, $array_output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => CC
    [3] => CCCC
    [4] => CCCCCC
    [5] => DDD
    [6] => EFG
    [7] => HIJ
    [8] => LMNOP
    [9] => 2
    [10] => b
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => six
    [6] => 78
    [7] => 9
    [8] => 10
)
```

If you need something that works like that on objects and arrays I've got a version for that, its not a quite a one liner though because behaviour changed subtly in RecursiveArrayIterator between PHP 5 and 7 despite what the PHP documentation says on this :|

The $iterator parameter has a method on it called getDepth() which can be used for fetching from a particular level within the comparison function

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I like it, with the only quibble I have being that the `$callback` requires a signature that embeds a requirement the function itself doesn't have, which makes it feel weird to me. So it really feels like syntactic glue.

Comment: The signature of the callable of recursive_select is compatible with array_filter rather than array_reduce, if you wanted to accumulate I'd suggest filtering with recursive_select and then accumulating after, filtering and accumulating in the same loop with array_reduce is closer to common foreach behaviour imo, where as the result of array_filter/recursive_select forces you to name your selection, which means it's easy to do multiple operations on it, whilst inside array_reduce accumulation and filtering is tightly coupled and hard to pass outside the function in a non accumulated fashion

Comment: That said, there can always be other things to consider like performance , or you may know you will not need access to the filtered data ever again, context trumps all if you're not ignorant to the trade offs being made, personally I err on the side of profiling first and being ready for code mutations that will need to occur in the future